# Why can I not interact with an HTML <template> element rendered by Blazor?

Tags: javascript, html, blazor, html-templates

Normally, if I have an `el: HTMLTemplateElement`, I can use `el.innerHTML` or `el.content.firstElementChild` to access its content. However, in this case, this `template` is rendered by Blazor and somehow all the content is inside a `#document-fragment` and I cannot access it:

[image]

Strangely enough, only `textContent` produces the text I want although normally it does not work on `<template>` (see the below code snippet for "normal" behavior).

What's happening here? How does Blazor make such a strange `template` element? I made sure the tag is actually `HTMLTemplateElement` and is not a Custom Element.

```js
const template = document.querySelector("template");
console.log(template.innerHTML);
console.log(template.content.firstElementChild);
console.log(template.textContent);
```

```html
<template><div>Hello</div></template>
```

The Blazor code:

```
<template data-markdown="true" style="display: none !important;">
    <div>
        @(ChildContent)
    </div>
</template>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the issue. Blazor does not simply print the HTML content, it attaches children element (probably using `appendChild`). The same behavior can be seen when we use `appendChild` on an `HTMLTemplateElement`:

[image]

```js
const t = document.querySelector("template");
const myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.innerHTML = "Hello there!";

t.appendChild(myDiv);

console.log(t.innerHTML);
console.log(t.textContent);
console.log(t.firstElementChild);
console.log(t.content.firstElementChild);
```

```html
<template></template>
```

A correct attempt should be:

```js
const t = document.querySelector("template");
const myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.innerHTML = "Hello there!";

t.content.appendChild(myDiv);

console.log(t.innerHTML);
console.log(t.textContent);
console.log(t.firstElementChild);
console.log(t.content.firstElementChild);
```

```html
<template></template>
```